# How to load Wordpress Post with Ajax onclick

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, loops, post

I have spent hours reading and trying tutorials. I cant seem to find a solution that works and I know it should be pretty easy but I struggle with AJAX. :(

I want to load Post content from a link in a div.
Below is what I have. Can someone please help me with the JavaScript side? Thanks!

```
<ul>
    <?php query_posts('post_type=artwork&posts_per_page=-1'); ?>
    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li class="mytab">
      <span>
         <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
         <a href="#"><?php the_post_thumbnail('Project'); ?></a>
      </span>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>

<div id="loadAjaxHere"></div>
```

I want to load this code in div #loadAjaxHere

```
<div class="myArtwork">
   <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
   <div class="text"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
</div>
```

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: What are you using to define which post you want to retrieve? what is the element that has the click function attached to it? are you familiar with the functions.php file?

Comment: You have to include wp-blog-header.php in the javascript side.

Comment: Try:
 $folder = substr(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],1), 0, strpos(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],1), "/"));
 $ajax_url = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'/'.$folder.'/wp-blog-header.php';
 require($ajax_url);
at the top of your external ajax request page.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy 
I was going to add something like:

<a href="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('Project'); ?></a>

to the .mytab class

Comment: I basically want to load a single post onclick using AJAX.
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok,
I think I have solved this after a long process of trial and error.

This seems to work, but please let me know if it is not the correct way of doing this

Javascript:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $("a.ajax").click(function(){
        var post_url = $(this).attr("href");
        var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#tabs").html('<div class="loading">loading...</div>');
    $("#tabs").load(post_url);
    return false;
    });
});
```

The page where I want to display the post content (I am using custom post types called "artwork":

```
<ul class="container">
  <?php query_posts('post_type=artwork&posts_per_page=-1'); ?>
  <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <li class="mytab">
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="ajax"><?php the_post_thumbnail('Project'); ?></a>
  </li>
  <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>

<!-- LOAD SINGLE POST CONTENT IN #TABS -->
<div id="tabs"></div>
```

And the single post "single-artwork.php". Note: Dont use get_header or get_footer etc:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="tabcontent" id="tab-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just to add, if you only want to load in part of the single post you can ammend

```
$("#tabs").load(post_url);
```

to

```
$("#tabs").load(post_url + ".tabcontent" );
```

Which would just load in everything in the div.tabcontent

Comment: Use a space between the commas and the point... $("#tabs").load(post_url + ' .tabcontent' );

Answer (score 3):

Barry's answer is correct about being able to load a partial page by adding a css selector expression to the end of the URL. However, there would need to be a space between the url and the selector like so:

```
$("#tabs").load(post_url + " .tabcontent" );
```

Otherwise the string passed to `.load()` would be `http://example.com.tabscontent`. But it should be `http://example.com .tabscontent`.

Also, a word to the wise, using this method will stop jQuery from loading and executing any code inside `<script>` tags. However, just using `.load(post_url);` without a selector would successfully load and execute code in `<script>` tags.

Read more about that [here](http://api.jquery.com/load#script-execution).